# Whatsapp through squid3

Tags: proxy, squid

I have squid3.5 installed on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm trying to configure squid to make WhatsApp work on mobile devices.
I tried to use the example written in the [squid3 docs](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Chat/Whatsapp) but it is not working.

I need the correct configuration to make WhatsApp working or any tutorial that will help me.

**Current Configurations for squid.conf:**

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 8000

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
#####################################################################
######### ** This are the lines i added from squid wiki **  #########
#####################################################################
acl DiscoverSNIHost at_step SslBump1
acl NoSSLIntercept ssl::server_name_regex "/etc/squid3/acl.url.nobump"
ssl_bump peek DiscoverSNIHost
ssl_bump splice NoSSLIntercept
ssl_bump bump all
```

**acl.url.nobump file:**

```
# Web.whatsapp.com
(w[0-9]+|[a-z]+)\.web\.whatsapp\.com
# Whatsapp CDN issue
.whatsapp\.net
```

and i installed squid3 like this:

```
./configure \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --exec-prefix=/usr \
        --includedir=/usr/include \
        --datadir=/usr/share \
        --libdir=/usr/lib64 \
        --libexecdir=/usr/lib64/squid \
        --localstatedir=/var \
        --sysconfdir=/etc/squid \
        --sharedstatedir=/var/lib \
        --with-logdir=/var/log/squid \
        --with-pidfile=/var/run/squid.pid \
        --with-default-user=squid \
        --enable-silent-rules \
        --enable-dependency-tracking \
        --with-openssl \
        --enable-icmp \
        --enable-delay-pools \
        --enable-useragent-log \
        --enable-esi \
        --enable-follow-x-forwarded-for \
        --enable-auth
```

Then I generated self-signed Certificate and installed it on my mobile

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.crt
```

**some log after browsing and then trying WhatsApp:**

/var/log/squid/cache.log

```
2018/06/19 14:45:40| Squid is already running!  Process ID 23347
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Shutdown: NTLM authentication.
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Shutdown: Negotiate authentication.
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Shutdown: Digest authentication.
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Shutdown: Basic authentication.
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Shutting down...
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
CPU Usage: 0.016 seconds = 0.012 user + 0.004 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 64128 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Logfile: closing log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Logfile Daemon: closing log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Open FD UNSTARTED     6 DNS Socket IPv6
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Open FD UNSTARTED     8 DNS Socket IPv4
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Open FD UNSTARTED     9 IPC UNIX STREAM Parent
2018/06/19 14:45:44 kid1| Squid Cache (Version 3.5.27): Exiting normally.
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.27 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Service Name: squid
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Process ID 23521
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Process Roles: worker
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| With 1024 file descriptors available
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Initializing IP Cache...
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 6
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 8
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Store logging disabled
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Target number of buckets: 1008
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Using 8192 Store buckets
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Using Least Load store dir selection
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Finished loading MIME types and icons.
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| HTCP Disabled.
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Pinger socket opened on FD 13
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Adaptation support is off.
2018/06/19 14:46:06 kid1| Accepting HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:8000 remote=[::] FD 11 flags=9
2018/06/19 14:46:06| pinger: Initialising ICMP pinger ...
2018/06/19 14:46:06|  icmp_sock: (1) Operation not permitted
2018/06/19 14:46:06| pinger: Unable to start ICMP pinger.
2018/06/19 14:46:06|  icmp_sock: (1) Operation not permitted
2018/06/19 14:46:06| pinger: Unable to start ICMPv6 pinger.
2018/06/19 14:46:06| FATAL: pinger: Unable to open any ICMP sockets.
2018/06/19 14:46:07 kid1| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
```

/var/log/squid/access.log

```
1529408773.577   1400 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6871 CONNECT login.live.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/131.253.61.84 -
1529408774.643    897 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 183 CONNECT a248.e.akamai.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/23.10.252.9 -
1529408774.643    887 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 183 CONNECT a248.e.akamai.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/23.10.252.9 -
1529408774.643    887 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 183 CONNECT a248.e.akamai.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/23.10.252.9 -
1529408774.647   1385 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3034 CONNECT ib.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.221.51 -
1529408774.650    874 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2777 CONNECT ib.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.221.51 -
1529408774.651   3548 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 177 CONNECT img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/23.212.108.190 -
1529408774.653   2493 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6098 CONNECT login.live.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/131.253.61.84 -
1529408774.657   4442 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3893 CONNECT m.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/37.252.172.180 -
1529408774.660    872 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 195 CONNECT m.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/37.252.172.180 -
1529408774.665    870 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 195 CONNECT m.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/37.252.172.180 -
1529408774.667   5508 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6297 CONNECT otf.msn.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/40.114.54.223 -
1529408774.672    854 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5716 CONNECT otf.msn.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/40.114.54.223 -
1529408774.696   2349 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3150 CONNECT ping.chartbeat.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.197.252.64 -
1529408774.704    882 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 184 CONNECT ping.chartbeat.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.197.252.64 -
1529408774.709    887 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 184 CONNECT ping.chartbeat.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.197.252.64 -
1529408774.711   4007 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 468 CONNECT sb.scorecardresearch.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.96.26.198 -
1529408774.715    888 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 191 CONNECT sb.scorecardresearch.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.96.26.198 -
1529408774.727    897 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 191 CONNECT sb.scorecardresearch.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.96.26.198 -
1529408774.745   5620 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6960 CONNECT www.bing.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/204.79.197.200 -
1529408774.745   2066 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6542 CONNECT otf.msn.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/40.114.54.223 -
1529408774.745   2520 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6542 CONNECT otf.msn.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/40.114.54.223 -
1529408775.018   1756 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3845 CONNECT ib.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.221.51 -
1529408776.063   1303 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5076 CONNECT ad.360yield.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.184.58.214 -
1529408776.397    298 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 277 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.18.228 -
1529408776.639   1884 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5076 CONNECT ad.360yield.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.184.58.214 -
1529408776.669   1904 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5076 CONNECT ad.360yield.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.184.58.214 -
1529408776.673   1889 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4490 CONNECT cm.adform.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/37.157.2.238 -
1529408776.673   1884 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5091 CONNECT dh.serving-sys.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.29.209.239 -
1529408776.679   1879 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5091 CONNECT dh.serving-sys.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.29.209.239 -
1529408776.684   1892 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5091 CONNECT dh.serving-sys.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.29.209.239 -
1529408776.690   1890 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 191 CONNECT dsum-sec.casalemedia.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2.20.170.241 -
1529408776.696   1876 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 191 CONNECT dsum-sec.casalemedia.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2.20.170.241 -
1529408776.717   1916 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 191 CONNECT dsum-sec.casalemedia.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/2.20.170.241 -
1529408776.725   1903 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5077 CONNECT eb2.3lift.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.184.92.103 -
1529408777.343    543 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5069 CONNECT bh.contextweb.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/151.101.0.166 -
1529408777.401   2576 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5077 CONNECT eb2.3lift.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.184.92.103 -
1529408777.407   2583 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5077 CONNECT eb2.3lift.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.184.92.103 -
1529408777.469   2641 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6317 CONNECT jadserve.postrelease.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.77.30.217 -
1529408777.497   3712 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6098 CONNECT login.live.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/131.253.61.84 -
1529408777.573   3795 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6098 CONNECT login.live.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/131.253.61.84 -
1529408778.419   4605 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5716 CONNECT otf.msn.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/40.114.54.223 -
1529408778.605   1824 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3277 CONNECT pixel.rubiconproject.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/213.19.162.80 -
1529408778.607   1873 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5805 CONNECT pm.w55c.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.19.23.162 -
1529408778.611   1243 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3510 CONNECT prebid.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/37.252.161.184 -
1529408778.617   1189 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3856 CONNECT prebid.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/37.252.161.184 -
1529408778.637   3808 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3388 CONNECT rtb-csync.smartadserver.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/185.86.139.19 -
1529408778.637   3807 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3388 CONNECT rtb-csync.smartadserver.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/185.86.139.19 -
1529408778.759   1929 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4556 CONNECT bid.socdm.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/202.241.208.2 -
1529408779.304   1756 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3163 CONNECT ib.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.221.51 -
1529408786.308  11221 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5119 CONNECT secure.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.220.231 -
1529408788.620  11015 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4451 CONNECT x.dlx.addthis.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.34.188.51 -
1529408802.161  23509 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3946 CONNECT encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.18.238 -
1529408802.558  24104 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 195 CONNECT ib.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.221.51 -
1529408802.568  23770 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 195 CONNECT ib.adnxs.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/103.243.221.51 -
1529408802.568  23912 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4089 CONNECT lh3.googleusercontent.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.18.225 -
1529408802.568  27740 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3388 CONNECT rtb-csync.smartadserver.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/185.86.139.19 -
1529408802.568  27728 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5005 CONNECT sync.teads.tv:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.213.171.180 -
1529408802.568  27726 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5005 CONNECT sync.teads.tv:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.213.171.180 -
1529408802.568  27732 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4573 CONNECT s.thebrighttag.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.228.243.159 -
1529408802.568  27736 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4573 CONNECT s.thebrighttag.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.228.243.159 -
1529408802.568  27734 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4573 CONNECT s.thebrighttag.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/54.228.243.159 -
1529408802.568  23894 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3947 CONNECT ssl.gstatic.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.18.227 -
1529408802.569  27730 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 193 CONNECT sync-tm.everesttech.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/151.101.2.49 -
1529408802.569  23890 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3948 CONNECT www.gstatic.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.18.227 -
1529408803.751   9840 172.19.88.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5172 CONNECT kinesis.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.119.185.54 -
```

Note: browsing http & https sites works fine

Comment: You're going to need to post a lot more information that "it doesn't work" if you want useful help. Common things that help people help you are configuration, tests, logs, etc.

Comment: i just added the configuration

Comment: is it possible to reopen the question again?

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information to diagnose the problem still. Which entry in the access log shows the Whatsapp Connection failing? It would be useful to demonstrate the problem. If you can do a CURL similar to how whatsapp accesses its server, ideally showing the corresponding log entries, that would be useful.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to Whatsapp Connection